# don't insert if value is the same MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to avoid duplication in below sql? you may say set the id as unique / PK, but I want it to be AI. and also a name could have the same address so I do not want to change anything. Thus I'm looking for alternative.

```
"INSERT INTO table(`id`,`name`,`address`) VALUES ($id,$name,$address)"
```

How to don't insert if the value existed?

Comment: `($id,'$name','$address')`

Comment: you question is not clear friend(i am not the downvoter)

Comment: I don't think MySQLi got AI feature. You are the programmer. You should write the 'AI'. Good Luck

Comment: If there is no way for you yourself to determine a criteria for uniqueness, how should SQL do it? First solve this completely detached from sql ot PHP, then apply your solution to SQL/PHP.

Comment: @Shiro AI mean auto-increment

Comment: @user790454 don't insert the same value if the value exist, is it so hard to understand?

Comment: yeah, i am bad in english. why dont you choose to set that column as unique?

Comment: @user790454 which column u mean?

Comment: the column in which you dont want to insert duplication values

Comment: @user790454 I did and it still duplicate because it's an AI

Comment: can you show what you have worked so far

Comment: @user790454 posted a question on stackoverflow

Comment: what??? i asked you to show what have you modified till now?

Comment: @user790454 posted another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545365/auto-increment-doesnt-work-with-unique-indexes LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column name and address fields as Key Type: `unique`. Your ID column still can keep it auto-increment and unique. Nothing conflict there.

Comment: I can't, they must duplicate.. coz 1 name can have 2 / more same address.

Comment: @user3522457 That's a bad design structure. One of the basic objective of saving data in a RDBMS is to uniquely identify each row. I suggest you create another table for ids that repeat and put in a foreign key reference on the main.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger my name and adress field is FK, it will be so messy if I split again.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger or I can use set instead of insert? which reinsert a row but update its value?

Comment: @user3522457 You can run a query to first check if ID exists, if it does, update it else insert. But this will work only for new ID that you enter from now on. If your column was unique you could have done this job with `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: @user3522457 then u shoud create another table for the address, this is 1 to N relationship. But your question is asking how to avoid duplication.. So get your question clear before you asking.