# auto_increment doesn't work with unique indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

says I've a table like this

```
uId | fatherOf | fatherOfTableId (AI)
```

to avoid duplication I should set fatherOfTableId unique, but I also want it to be AI. The problem with it is it still duplicate. For example this may happen:

```
uId | fatherOf | fatherOfTableId (AI)
1     2          1
1     2          2
```

U may say why not give uId / fatherOf field unique index? I can't as one uId can have many fatherOf and one fatherOf can have many uId. I wish not to split my table as this is already a bridge table. Any solution?

Comment: Can you post the cleaned up version of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for this?

Comment: @tadman u want desc table?

Comment: what is this buddy,you dont want it to have duplicate values? but it can duplicate values???? better try to check while inserting whether there is already a row which is having these two values.

Comment: @user790454 I want it to have duplicate values, and by default it allows that. my sayings of to avoid duplication means if a record is there, I don't want to insert it again. Assume it's like check if user exist then insert.

Comment: that is what i said,check it before insertion

Comment: @user790454 check what? check 3 field?

Comment: ohhhhhh no man,,uId and fatherOf no need to check AI id

Comment: What language are you two speaking? This is getting really hard to understand.

Comment: @user790454 I see.. thx man.. seem like that's the best solution